# Code iterates through all rows and inserts value in cell for each

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I would like that this code would now be done in a faster way:

```
Sub TechMapping()

    Set mappingWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="path\workbook1.xlsx")
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Dim Lookup_Range As Range
    Set Lookup_Range = Range("A2:P1779")

    Workbooks("workbook2.xlsb").Activate
    Set sh = ActiveSheet

    Dim i As Long   
    i = 2
    Do While i <= LastRow

        Set appid = sh.Range("A" & i)
        Set appnonapp = sh.Range("B" & i)
        Set customercountry = sh.Range("G" & i)
        Set lastactuals = sh.Range("P" & i)
        Set lasttotal = sh.Range("O" & i)

        If appnonapp.Value = "condition1" And customercountry.Value = "country1" Then

            Dim DStest As Variant
            DStest = Application.VLookup(appid, Lookup_Range, 7, False)

            If IsError(DStest) Then

                i = i + 1
                GoTo Line1

            Else

                Dim totalDS As Integer
                totalDS = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(appid, Lookup_Range, 6, False)

                Dim columnnr As Integer
                columnnr = 7

                If totalDS = 1 Then

                    appid.Offset(columnoffset:=16) = Application.VLookup(appid, Lookup_Range, columnnr, False)

                Else

                    appid.Offset(columnoffset:=16) = Application.VLookup(appid, Lookup_Range, columnnr, False)
                    appid.Offset(columnoffset:=15) = lastactuals / totalDS
                    appid.Offset(columnoffset:=14) = lasttotal / totalDS

                    For j = 1 To totalDS - 1

                        Dim newcolumn As Integer
                        newcolumn = 7 + 2 * j 

                        sh.Rows(i).Copy
                        sh.Rows(i).Offset(j).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                        appid.Offset(j, 16) = Application.VLookup(appid, Lookup_Range, newcolumn, False)
                        LastRow = LastRow + 1

                    Next j

                    Application.CutCopyMode = False

                End If

            End If

    ElseIf appnonapp.Value = "condition1" And customercountry.Value <> "country1" Then ' Step 9

            appid.Offset(columnoffset:=16) = "option 1"

        ElseIf appnonapp.Value = "condition2" And customercountry.Value <> "country1" Then ' Step 10

            appid.Offset(columnoffset:=16) = "option 2"

        ElseIf appnonapp.Value <> "condition2" And appnonapp.Value <> "condition1" And customercountry.Value <> "country1" Then ' Step 11

            appid.Offset(columnoffset:=16) = "option 3"

        Else

        End If

        i = i + totalDS

    Line1:
    Loop
```

From what i have realized, i believe it's possible to store all values i want to insert in a temporary variable and then insert them all at once instead of doing the insert at every single row iteration. This would considerably reduce the execution time for this code.

Comment: @pacmaninbw This is asking for advice of a specific refactoring which is on-topic here. It is essentially "How can I refactor this code to make it faster?"

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ See above comment.

Comment: @SimonForsberg OK, I see. May be should be edited to sound less about not yet written code.

Comment: So that we don't have to reverse-engineer the code, could you summarize what "this code" achieves? We can't see your worksheets, so some examples would be helpful too. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
Range("A1:D1") = Array("One", "Two", "Three", "Four")
```

If that's what you're referring to.

Also using .Activate, ActiveSheet and .Select are bad practice. Use instead [With Statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> GoTo Line1
> ```

I saw that and scrolled *up*, thinking I had missed a line label somewhere. `Line1` is a terrible name for a line label, *especially* in a language that supports numbered lines. That's not "line 1" at all.

Had that instruction read like this:

```
GoTo NextRow
```

I would have known right away that I was looking at the single legit use of `GoTo` in VBA - that `GoTo` jump essentially means `Continue`, a keyword that doesn't exist in VBA.

---

Your variable names are distractingly inconsistent:

```
mappingWB       ' camelCase, with an abbreviation
Lookup_Range    ' PascalCase, with underscores
sh              ' disemvoweled lowercase
customercountry ' all-lowercase
```

Pick a style, stick to it. I'd recommend using `PascalCase` (no underscores) for public members, and `camelCase` (no disemvoweling, no abbreviations, no underscores) for locals and parameters.

Avoid the underscore in identifiers. An underscore has enough meanings as it is in VBA:

- When preceded with a space, it's a *line continuation* token
- When part of a member name, it's in the form of `ObjectName_MemberName` for event handlers and interface implementations.

Note that a public member with an underscore in its name cannot legally be part of an implementable interface - so there's a real reason well beyond "just style" for avoiding underscores in member names.

---

You're not declaring all your variables, and you rely on implicit calls to default members - this *will* end up biting you in the rear end.

Put this at the top of **every single module**:

```
Option Explicit
```

And then declare your variables, until VBA can compile your code. Without this, VBA will happily compile code that contains typos, allocating on-the-fly `Variant` memory space for whatever comes along; this rarely results in code working as it should, and makes code excruciatingly hard to debug - for no reason at all.

---

You `Set` these undeclared locals (assuming they're locals):

> ```
>     Set appid = sh.Range("A" & i)
>     Set appnonapp = sh.Range("B" & i)
>     Set customercountry = sh.Range("G" & i)
>     Set lastactuals = sh.Range("P" & i)
>     Set lasttotal = sh.Range("O" & i)
> ```

This makes them `Variant/Range` object references... but you use them as `Range` objects or as `Double` values indiscriminately:

> ```
>     appid.Offset(columnoffset:=16) = Application.VLookup(appid, Lookup_Range, columnnr, False)
>     appid.Offset(columnoffset:=15) = lastactuals / totalDS
>     appid.Offset(columnoffset:=14) = lasttotal / totalDS
> ```

Left-hand side has `appid` treated as a `Range` reference, right-hand side has `appid`, `lastactuals` and `lasttotal` treated as a `Double` value. And since `appid`, `lastactuals` and `lasttotal` aren't declared, every single call is a late-bound `IDispatch` interface query. Compare to:

```
Dim appIdRange As Range
Set appIdRange = sh.Range("A" & i)

Dim appId As Double
appId = appIdRange.Value
```

This is somewhat explicit code. Notice something? The `.Value` variant is being coerced into a `Double` - if the VBA runtime can't do it (e.g. cell contains an error, or a string that can't be implicitly converted to a double), you get a run-time error. This can easily be avoided:

```
Dim appIdRange As Range
Set appIdRange = sh.Range("A" & i)

If IsError(appIdRange.Value) Then GoTo NextLine

Dim appId As Double
appId = appIdRange.Value
```

Now, we don't like `GoTo` jumps - they make the code jump up and down and quickly turn everything into a mess. One way to avoid that is to *extract a method* out of the loop body.

```
Do While i <= LastRow
    ProcessRow sh, i, lookupRange ', ...
Loop
```

And now this `ProcessRow` procedure can use the much cleaner `Exit Sub` instruction to walk back up to the calling code after validating its arguments, effectively skipping a loop iteration - only, `ProcessRow` doesn't even know (or care) about a loop: it's only ever concerned about a single row.

---

Performance-wise, your code is slow for a number of reasons:

- Late-bound `IDispatch` interface queries off `Variant/Range` object references are much slower than early-bound `Range` member calls.
- Working with ranges and calculating offsets is inherently slow.
- Inserting rows via the clipboard is slow, especially with `Application.ScreenUpdating` left enabled, `Application.Calculation` mode left on automatic, and `Application.EnableEvents` firing workbook and worksheet events everytime the slightest thing changes on any cell.

> *From what I have realized, I believe it's possible to store all values I want to insert in a temporary variable and then insert them all at once instead of doing the insert at every single row iteration. This would considerably reduce the execution time for this code.*

Absolutely. Go ahead, do it! Work with arrays instead of ranges, only ever access the worksheet when you *have* to, and your code will run much faster.

Also, you're doing redundant lookups:

> ```
> Dim DStest As Variant
> DStest = Application.VLookup(appid, Lookup_Range, 7, False)
> ```

At every single value of `i`, you have the lookup value at the 7th column (whatever that is - consider declaring local `Const` values to replace these magic numbers), stored in `DStest`.

But then you do this:

> ```
>     Dim columnnr As Integer
>     columnnr = 7
>
>     If totalDS = 1 Then
>
>         appid.Offset(columnoffset:=16) = Application.VLookup(appid, Lookup_Range, columnnr, False)
>
>     Else
> ```

`columnnr` can only ever be `7` here, which makes that lookup entirely redundant - you're going to get the exact same value you already have in `DStest`.

But it gets worse - you have the same redundant lookup in the `Else` block too, and then you have that hard-coded `7` here again, in that inner `j` loop:

> ```
>     Else
>
>         appid.Offset(columnoffset:=16) = Application.VLookup(appid, Lookup_Range, columnnr, False)
>         appid.Offset(columnoffset:=15) = lastactuals / totalDS
>         appid.Offset(columnoffset:=14) = lasttotal / totalDS
>
>         For j = 1 To totalDS - 1
>
>             Dim newcolumn As Integer
>             newcolumn = 7 + 2 * j 
>
>             sh.Rows(i).Copy
>             sh.Rows(i).Offset(j).Insert Shift:=xlDown
>             appid.Offset(j, 16) = Application.VLookup(appid, Lookup_Range, newcolumn, False)
>             LastRow = LastRow + 1
>
>         Next j
> ```

Should that `7` ever need to turn into a `8`, you've almost guaranteed a bug here. This entire block of code should be inside its own scope.

These `Offset` ranges make things much more confusing than they need to be - and these late-bound lookups are going to be slow.

---

If it wasn't of the `IsError` check at the beginning of the loop, this one would throw a run-time error:

> ```
> Dim totalDS As Integer
> totalDS = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(appid, Lookup_Range, 6, False)
> ```

`WorksheetFunction.VLookup` is an early-bound call, and if that lookup fails you'll get a VBA run-time error - as opposed to `Application.VLookup`, which *returns* an error value, *à la* Excel 95. But there's another problem: you're narrowing the result into a 16-bit integer, but if the cell contains a numeric value, it would be a `Double`, not an `Integer`: there's a risk of an *overflow* here, should the lookup ever yield a value greater than 32,767. Regardless of the "possible values" here, the code shouldn't have to care about them - it's reading a `Double` and implicitly forcing it into an `Integer`: it spells trouble, and there's no reason for it. Best declare `totalDS As Double` and rule out that possibility.

---

The indentation is confused and confusing. Consider using an indenter tool like [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation) (disclaimer: I'm heavily involved in that open-source project) to do it for you. As a bonus you'll get *code inspections*, that will tell you many other things about your code - including things that I missed in my review, for example the fact that `j` isn't declared, or that `mappingWB` is never used anywhere.